# Почему behavior yii2 не поддерживает события?

Tags: yii2, behaviors

Класс `Behavior` расширяет `Object`, но только класс `Component` имеет метод `trigger()`. Я бы хотел иметь возможность подписать обработчик события, которое генерирует сам `Behavior`, например так

```
SomeController extends Controller {
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            [
                'class' => MyBehavior::class,
                'on someEvent' => // handler
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Может есть какие-то идеологические причины, так не делать?

Comment: [Behavior::events()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-behavior.html#events()-detail) - не?

Comment: Нет, это события owner класса, а мне хотелось бы в самом классе behavior сделать так $this->trigger()